# Expand all Node by checking a Single Node CheckBox in Telerik TreeView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I load a telerik Treeview that contains parent, child and siblings. If i click any parents checkbox means all nodes for that particular node to be expanded. How to do this?
I used this javascript code. It expands a single node under the checked parent node. But the fact is that, it contains multiple nodes that cannot be expanded. I use load on Demand in this Telerik TreeView. Pls help me..

```
function TreeChecked(e) {
    var treeview = $("#CategoryTreeView").data('tTreeView');
    var Nodes = $(e.item);
    treeview.expand(Nodes);
    AllExpand(treeview, e.item)
}
function AllExpand(treeview, e) {
    var Nodes = $(e).find("li");
    treeview.expand(Nodes);
    AllExpand(treeview, e);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want to expand all the child nodes and grand child nodes when clicked on parent?

Comment: Yeah you are correct @AmitChotaliya

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this will but this will give you basic idea how to do it recursively.
Try the below code to call AllExpand for inner nodes. Note that this code is not tested so you may need to do some additional changes.

```
function AllExpand(treeview, e) {
    var Nodes = $(e).find("li");
    if(Nodes.lenght > 0){
        treeview.expand(Nodes);    
        for(var i=0;i<Nodes.lenght;i++){
            AllExpand(treeview, Nodes[i]);
        }    
    }
    return;    
}
```

Comment: it expand only one level of nodes only